# Publish Flash swf on WEB for tablets and desktops

Tags: android, ios, air, flash

I have a project in .swf and it is ok displayed on desktop but if I want to view that page from Android device, it needs Abobe flash player which is not suported by that device.

Can anyone help me how to solve this problem and display that swf for all devices (Desktop, Android, iOS)?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Publish settings in Flash and set Target to AIR…Desktop, AIR…iOS or AIR…Android then publish.